# Найти недостающую пару в массиве и вывести число в консоль

Tags: c#, .net

Есть одномерный массив из положительных и отрицательных чисел. Нужно найти в массиве те числа, в результате которых получится 0, например 1 и -1. А если такой пары нет, то вывести отдельно недостающее число. Например нашли -4, но не нашли 4, значит, его и выводим отдельно.

Отрывок кода, который работает, но не до конца выводит найденные числа.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (myArr[i] - myArr[j] == 0 | myArr[j] - myArr[i] == 0)  //Если результат 0, выводим в консоль                        
                            Console.WriteLine(myArr[i]+ " " +myArr[j]);
                    else
                    //Вывести недостающее число,к найденному числу
                }
            }
```

Код не прошу, а лишь примерный алгоритм или объяснение, как мне действовать дальше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так, на случай, если все числа уникальны и не встречаются более одного раза, иначе всё сложнее будет:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            {
                bool флагВсёПрошлиПаруНеНашли = true;
                for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (myArr[i] + myArr[j] == 0) 
                    {
                            //Если результат 0, выводим в консоль                        
                            Console.WriteLine(myArr[i]+ " " +myArr[j]);
                            флагВсёПрошлиПаруНеНашли = false;
                            break
                    }
                }
                //Вывести недостающее число,к найденному числу
                if(флагВсёПрошлиПаруНеНашли)
                {
                    // у myArr[i] нет пары, нужно об этом сообщить
                }
            }
```